# XML Output is Truncated in SQL

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, ssms

I need to return my result set in XML and this works fine, but if the number of records are increased, my xml output is `truncated` here is my query

```
select t.id,t.name,t.address from test FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('Response'), ELEMENTS
```

However I have set some option to increase the output result set like..

```
Tools --> Options --> Query Results --> SQL Server --> Results to Text --> Maximum              
number of characters displayed in each column
Tools --> Options --> Results --> Maximum characters per column
```

but still I am unable to get my desired result.

please suggest my solution

EDIT: However when I click on the XML, it open in another query window and all xml shown here, but it not return all xml instead of truncated xml.

Thanks....

Comment: Make sure you restart SSMS Management Studio for these changes to take effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same problem with management studio and xml result sets. I've solved this by getting the output programatically with c#, with SqlDataReader.

Comment: If you add an example I'll give you +1

Answer (score 65):

Try the following:

```
Declare @xmldata xml
set @xmldata = (select ... From test for xml...)
select @xmldata as returnXml
```

Comment: This allowed me to avoid using the XmlReader.

Comment: This answer worked great for me and should be marked as the answer.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Great tip!  Note: works **only** when SQL Server 2014 SSMS is set for 'query results to grid' (ctrl+d).  Does not work 'to file' or 'to text'.  So I copy/pasted from the grid cell into my editor.

Comment: See [this stack overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230424/cant-set-output-of-with-xmlnamespaces-for-xml-path-to-a-variable) if you need to prepend WITH XMLNAMESPACES as the set = ( ... ) syntax does not work with WITH in this case.

Comment: This works for Sql Server 2016 FOR JSON PATH as well

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me (SSMS 2012):
Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid: Maximum Characters Retried: XML data: Unlimited.
Then I saved the results of the grid to a file.

Comment: Answer that helped me, but as mentioned by Tim Clauss https://stackoverflow.com/a/66141674/10010199 one has to completely restart SQL Server for the change to take effect

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I changes my Query result setting to Unlimited, but it didnt work. There is a work around. Its not very neat, but if you do want to continue to use SQL Server Management studio and get the results. Tweak the query to convert the xml stored using:

```
convert(xml,'<xml><![CDATA[' + cast(MyColumnWithXml as varchar(max)) + ']]></xml>')
```

The complete text is returned. Please note you will have to do some formatting at you end

Answer (score 4):

Just thought I'd add a quick addition to the answer above.  Changing the settings in SSMS 2017 Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid works.  However you must then close SSMS entirely and re-open it for the setting to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

If your XML result set is still being truncated even after changing SSMS Options, use the SQLCMD utility with :XML ON option prior to running your XML statement.  Direct your output to a file using the -o switch.  SQLCMD is a command line utility that is very simple to use.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx.

Comment: Might only work with MS SQL 2008 or earlier. MS SQL 2012 will cut it off: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/786004/sqlcmd-with-xml-on-break-lines-on-large-output

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked like **10 Years** ago, but still if someone is looking for a workaround which doesn't require any changes in the DB side and is a bit similar to the Accepted answer but not with `SqlDataReader`.

You could make use of a `DataTable` and fill it using the `SqlDataAdapter`. Where your  `XML` data will be divided into multiple rows.

> For Example

```
string xmloutput = "";
var cmd = new SqlCommand("<some sql query that returns data in xml format>", con);
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
var dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        xmloutput  += dr[0].ToString();
    }
```

**Note:**

- the above code assumes that the only one column is returned from `DB` with `XML` data in it.

And later on, make use of the variable `xmloutput`.

Answer (score 0):

The XML output you get in Query output window is not really intended for saving
valid XML documents. You can get valid XML out of SQL Server when you
capture it as a stream using ADO or SQLXML managed classes in .NET

However you can limit the query output sizes by using 
In SQL Server Management Studio go to Tools >> Options >> Query Results >> SQL Server >> Results to Text >> Maximum number of characters displayed in each column

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Management Studio for 2008 against a SQL Server 2005 database engine.  If you do that, the defaults should be large enough, but in Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server there is a Results to Grid and Results To Text node.

Results to Grid allows you to control the maximum size for XML data explicitly, and the default maximum size is 2MB.

If you don't have a license for SSMS 2008 you should be able to use the express edition for free [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en).