# Can't set output of 'WITH XMLNAMESPACES...FOR XML PATH' to a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, namespaces, for-xml

I have a query like the following:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://www.somewhere.com')
SELECT ( 'SOMETHING' )
FOR XML PATH('RootNode'), TYPE
```

Running this works fine. However, I run into troubles when I try to set the XML output to a variable like this:

```
DECLARE @MYXML AS XML

SELECT @MYXML = (
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://www.somewhere.com')
SELECT ( 'SOMETHING' )
FOR XML PATH('RootNode'), TYPE
)
```

This just give me a syntax error :-(  Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MYXML AS XML

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://www.somewhere.com')
SELECT @MYXML = (
   SELECT ( 'SOMETHING' )
   FOR XML PATH('RootNode'), TYPE)
```