# FOR XML PATH results in SSMS truncated to 2034 characters

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm concatenating strings together using "for xml path('')".

I have set the Tools->Options->SQL Server->Results to Grid options to max.

I have set the Tools->Options->SQL Server->Results to Text options to max.

Executing the query in Grid mode and copying the one row/one colum results, I see the return value is limited to 2034 characters.

Executing the query in Text mode and copying the one row/one colum results, I see the return value is limited to 1124 characters.

How can I ensure the returned value isn't truncated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML Output is Truncated in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742651/xml-output-is-truncated-in-sql)

Comment: @RowlandShaw keep it up, you almost have 30,000 internet points!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658758/609058

For some reason, converting the XML to a string returns a non-truncated string.

Not sure why it works, but it does.

Comment: There is an issue with the .NET SQL Server Client that causes this (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310378). Microsoft suggest using SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader instead of SqlCommand.ExecuteReader to work around the issue.

Comment: I've provided an example powershell script if anyone's interested in [another topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27613908/2226686)