# sql adds unwanted characters in xml tag

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a sql procedure that generates a xml whit some data from a table. My problem is that sometimes it generates the xml with errors, and more specific it adds a extra character to one of my xml. It is always the same tag and if i remove the tag it does that with the previous tag. Basically in the same position of the xml no matter the tag. Here is my sql code:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[genUserVehicleXML]
@userID nvarchar(450)

as
BEGIN
declare @IMEI nvarchar(138),@totalKM decimal(16,4),@funcH decimal(16,4),                              @stayH decimal(16,4),  @totalH decimal(16,4),@dayKM decimal(16,4)

DECLARE contact_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT IMEI FROM ClientsIMEI where ApplicationUserId=@userID


OPEN contact_cursor;  

 -- Perform the first fetch.  
 FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor
 into @IMEI;  

 -- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.  
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
 BEGIN  
 -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds. 
  select @totalKM=cast (sum(Kilometers)/cast(1000 as decimal(16,4)) as   decimal(16,4)) from Properties where IMEI=@IMEI
  select @dayKM=cast (sum(Kilometers)/cast(1000 as decimal(16,4)) as decimal(16,4)) from Properties where IMEI=@IMEI and day(Time_Stamp)=day(getdate())
  select @funcH=cast (sum(Properties.Hours)/cast(3600 as decimal(16,4)) as decimal(16,4)) from Properties where IMEI=@IMEI and EngineStatus=1 and day(Time_Stamp)=day(getdate())
  select @stayH=cast (sum(Properties.Hours)/cast(3600 as decimal(16,4)) as decimal(16,4)) from Properties where IMEI=@IMEI and EngineStatus=0 and day(Time_Stamp)=day(getdate())
  select @totalH=cast (sum(Properties.Hours)/cast(3600 as decimal(16,4)) as decimal(16,4)) from Properties where IMEI=@IMEI
  INSERT INTO dbo.XMLData
  select top 1 P.IDProperty,p.ApplicationUserId,
            P.IMEI,P.Time_Stamp,
            P.Latitude,
            P.Longitude,
            P.Speed,
            P.FuelLevel,
            P.EngineStatus,
            isnull(@dayKM,0),
            C.InitialKilometers+@totalKM,
            isnull(@funcH,0),
            isnull(@stayH,0),
            isnull(@totalH,0)+C.InitialHours,
            isnull(@totalH,0),
            P.Angle,
            P.Altitude,
            P.Satellites,
            C.IDClientsIMEI,
            C.CarNumber,
            C.DriverName,
            C.Model 
            from Properties P join ClientsIMEI C on P.IMEI=c.IMEI where   P.ApplicationUserId=@userID and P.IMEI=@IMEI  order by Time_Stamp desc 
   FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor into @IMEI;  
   END  



   CLOSE contact_cursor;  
   DEALLOCATE contact_cursor;   


     DECLARE @fileName NVARCHAR(1000)

     DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(1000)
     DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000)

     SET @fileName = 'C:\gps_beta01\wwwroot\outputXML_'+ @userID +'.xml'

     SET @sqlStr = 'select [IDProperty],[ApplicationUserId], [IMEI],convert(varchar(50),cast([Time_Stamp] as datetime),20) as [Time_Stamp],[Latitude],[Longitude],
convert(numeric(16,0),cast([Speed] as float)) as Speed,convert(numeric(16,0),cast([FuelLevel] as float)) as FuelLevel,[EngineStatus],
convert(numeric(16,2),cast([Kilometers] as float))as Kilometers,[KilometersTotal],[FunctionHours],
[StationHours],[TotalHours],[TotalH],convert(numeric(16,0),cast([Angle] as float)) as Angle,convert(numeric(16,0),cast([Altitude] as float)) as Altitude,
[Satellites],[IDClientsIMEI] as [IDClients],replace([CarNumber],'' '','''') as [Number] ,[DriverName],[Model] from gpsTEST.dbo.XMLDATA for xml path (''Vehicle''), root (''Vehicles'')'


     SET @sqlCmd= 'bcp "'+ @sqlStr+'" QUERYOUT '+@fileName+' -c -t, -T -S' +  @@SERVERNAME;

      EXEC Master..xp_CmdShell @sqlCmd
      delete XMLData



      END
```

And this is a jpeg with xml after I checked it with a xml online validator:
[image]

This happens everytime only at that position. Please help cause I don't know what is happening.

Update:
 this is a link with the xml : https://www.dropbox.com/s/9b10s1x2l85l8lf/outputXML_ccbfcf7e-2086-41ef-9e98-ef0b0084c8f4.xml?dl=0

Comment: Can you post the xml, or at least a snippet of it to show the problem?

Comment: it's in the jpeg. at the last row in the tag <\Number> it adds a "2" and it becomes <\2Number>

Comment: It's not clear from the jpeg what characters are genuinely part of the xml, and which are part of the markup added by the validator. If you could post the pure xml, that would be helpful.

Comment: See the update in my answer... Your DropBox example includes a line break, but no numbers... `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH()` would not add any silly line breaks... Why are you using `bcp -t,`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: This is a really ugly approach. There is no need for a cursor at all... It was much better (and easier!) to solve this set-based...

But to your question: Your *This happens everytime only at that position* is not true. Look at your picture: There is a `1` at the middle of your page. This is not breaking any element name, but - obviously - The XML is somehow broken in parts and theses parts are numbered. I'm quite sure, that there is exactly the same count from the start to the floating `1` as there is from there to the `2` which is breaking your XML element's name. Find out, if these numberes are included in the XML file already...

### UPDATE:

As expected your DropBox-link points to valid XML... The only bad is a line break, which should not be there... Cannot see any silly numbers... They come into your file somewhere later...

### UPDATE 2:

Lines are terminated with a line break by default. You can find a list of options [here: Specify Field and Row Terminators (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485.aspx). With XML-BULK-export it is advised to use `-r` or `-N` (but no `-t`)

Comment: But look closely! There are no silly numbers... I think, that you get line breaks after a given count of characters (why ever). And your validation adds line numbers...

Comment: @CodrutRotaru, the option `-t` seems to be wrong, but I do not think, that this is the reason... If you look into your XML file on your disk with a simple editor: Are there any line breaks? Count the characters between them...

Comment: I checked in sql server and when I execute the procedure I get 2 warning. Perhaps they are related to my problem                                                        "(1 row(s) affected)
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(1 row(s) affected)
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
"

Comment: @CodrutRotaru I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27151109/5089204. The *network paket size* could be a point... Your line break appears quite exactly at half of this value. As this is written in Unicode (2 bytes per character), I have the idea, that each packet is written with a line break. Try without the small `-t,` option!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add `-r` to the bcp command.

```
SET @sqlCmd= 'bcp "'+ @sqlStr+'" QUERYOUT '+@fileName+' -c  -T -r -S' +  @@SERVERNAME;
```

I found the solution here: [SQL Server Bcp Export XML Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321341/sql-server-bcp-export-xml-format)