# can xp_cmdshell bcp deal with "<"?

Tags: sql-server, xml, bcp

I'm trying to write an XML formatted SQL output into a file from a stored procedure (I know, not recommended, but it's a last resort).

I think I'm missing something though. I have a variable @cmd that when printed gives me

```
bcp "<TRNUID>2016-05-31T00:00:00</TRNUID>...</DJ_LINE></ROWADDRQ>" queryout C:\xxx\xxx\out.xml -c -S xxx\SQLEXPRESS -U xxxx -P xxxx
```

When I do

`exec xp_cmdshell @cmd;`

This gives me the error "< was unexpected at this time."

Can anyone point me in the right direction for resolving this?

Comment: `bcp` expects a SQL statement, and a SQL Statement doesn't start with `<`. perhaps you mean `bcp "SELECT '<TRN...</ROWADDRQ> AS XMLValue;" queryout...`?

Comment: See eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321341/sql-server-bcp-export-xml-format

Comment: @Larnu 's comment did the trick!